# Altium Designer: Design Rule Check didn't check for all my nets?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

I'v been using Hierarchical Schematic Design. In my design, there were 76 nets as shown below:

[image]

here is my Design Rule Checker:

[image]

But when I run DRC(Design Rule Check) while I left all the connections as shown below:

[image]

DRC didn't check for all the nets, only 22 nets was checked:

[image]

Whyyy? Did I miss something? Or when I'm using Hierarchical Schematic Design i need to enable something??, Because i can not check for all my net connections after i finish.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: What is the total number of errors reported? There is an upper limit of errors generated before DRC just bails out.

Comment: @asdfex Thank you so much! there were 500 violations, and i didn't notice that, they had limitation of number of errors. So, Can i change that value up to more than 500 errors?

Comment: Dangit I was going to say that but decided not to =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an upper limit of 500 errors (in total) reported. Which errors are reported or not seems to be quite random if this limit is exceeded.

You can change the default value in Tools -> Design Rule Check -> "Stop when X violations are found"